# Unit Test case for Sorting in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am new to reactjs and jest. I am trying to write a test case that will pass the sort function written in container. I am not sure how to write it.

I am getting  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined` error when I try to run the test case.

Actual Array

```
let testArray=[{trackingId:'1',updated: '1512885243'},
                {trackingId:'1',updated: '1512485253'},
                {trackingId:'3',updated: '1512884233'},
                {trackingId:'2',updated: '1512885243'}];
```

Expected Array

```
let sortedArray = [{trackingId: '1', updated: '1512885243'},
                   {trackingId: '1', updated: '1512885253'},
                 {trackingId: '2', updated: '1512885243'},
                 {trackingId: '3', updated: '1512884233'}]

// I am thinking something like:
describe('Sorting', () => {
      it('Array should be sortedby trackingId', () => {
        testArray.sort((a,b) => {
          if (a.trackingId !== b.trackingId) {
            return a.trackingId - b.trackingId;
          }
          return new Date(b.updated) - new Date(a.updated);
        });
        expect(component.contains(result))
          .toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(sortedArray))

});
```

Sort function in my container class for which I am writing the unit test:

```
customerTrackingInfo = customerTrackingInfo.sort( (a,b) => {
        if (a.trackingId !== b.trackingId) {
          return a.trackingId - b.trackingId;
        }
        return new Date(b.updated) - new Date(a.updated);
});
```

Comment: That error means that testArray is undefined. Have you put the definition in the same file as the test or are you importing it?

Answer (score 5):

I like how elegant @Rafał Figura's answer is, but it has one one major flaw, which is that even though [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) returns a sorted array, it sorts the original array *in place*, mutating it. This means that

```
expect(array).toStrictEqual(array.sort(sortingFunction))
```

will always pass since `array.sort(sortingFunction)` will update `array` to be the sorted value. The fix is simple, though. Just copy the array before sorting it:

```
expect(array).toStrictEqual([...array].sort(sortingFunction))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found good way to test if array is sorted properly.

Just use:

```
  expect(array).toStrictEqual(array.sort(sortingFunction*))
```

When sorting function is not set, default sorting order is ascending.

You can read more about sorting [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)